# Define the default member for non-aggregatable attribute SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2012

I am new in using the analysis services SSAS. I am trying to turn off the ALL level hierarchy by changing the IsAggregatable from True to False on the first attribute on the hierarchy level i.e. County. However, I got a warning states

```
Warning 1   DimensionAttribute [Customer].[Country] : Define the default member for non-aggregatable attributes in either the DefaultMember property or the cubes' MDX script.      0   0
```

In addition, the country attributes has a blue curly error underneath it! Does the country attribute not aggregatable and how do I get rid off the warning ?

Comment: Why is it not valid to get a grand total of any measure across all countries?

Comment: If users don't specify a country in a filter then what country's numbers should show by default?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Countries are showing all at the moment and user can get ALL shown and his is when I browse the dimension. My intention is to show countries and the user can filter accordingly. By default ALL countries are showing when users don't specify

Comment: I would only turn off the All member on dimensions like the Currency dimension where it is nonsensical to add Dollars and Euros together. In your case I would just put a slicer or parameter in the report to have the user filter to a country if they want.